# UNIX directory management

Tags: unix

When I try typing this "cp /etc/passwd~/dir1/mypasswd" into my Ubuntu terminal I get an error message that says "cp: missing destination file operand after `/etc/passwd~/dir1/mypasswd' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cp` needs two arguments, you are missing a space

```
  cp /etc/passwd ~/dir1/mypasswd
```

Answer (score 0):

The general format for cp command is:

```
cp source_file target_file
```

The cp utility copies the contents of the
source_file to the target_file. The names of the files themselves are not changed.  If
cp detects an attempt to copy a file to itself, the copy will fail. And according to your error message, you are missing the name of your destination file.

For more information about cp, you can do `man cp` anytime in your terminal.